# How to implement a UserFactory using IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I used to have a `UserFactory` (before vNext) that used `HttpContext.Current` but since that is now gone I am having trouble recreating it.

I want it to be a static class that sets and gets the current user to access user data throughout the application.

I know I must use the DI system but not sure how.

**Code so far:**

```
public class CurrentContext : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor ctx;

        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get
            {
                return ctx.HttpContext;
            }

            set
            {
                ctx.HttpContext = value;
            }
        }
    }


services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, CurrentContext>();

    public class UserFactory
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _context;

        public UserFactory(IHttpContextAccessor Context)
        {
            _context = Context;
        }

        public void Add(string s) => _context.HttpContext.Session.SetString(s, s);

        public string Get(string s) => _context.HttpContext.Session.GetString(s);
}
```

How can I get a `UserFactory` instance anywhere in my app with the current context?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the `UserFactory` class non-static and register it as scoped:

```
services.AddScoped<UserFactory>();
```

This will create one instance per web request. You can inject this into every other class and let the `UserFactory` take a dependency on `IHttpContextAccessor` to get the current HttpContext.

This adheres to the dependency inversion philosophy Microsoft is trying to implement in ASP.NET 5. Static classes do not really fit into this and should be avoided as much as possible.

---

**Example**

`UserFactory` class:

```
public class UserFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    // other code...
}
```

`ConfigureServices()` in `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddScoped<UserFactory>();

    // ...
}
```

Now you can inject an instance of `UserFactory` in a controller for example:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserFactory _userFactory;  

    public SomeController(UserFactory userFactory)
    {
        _userFactory = userFactory;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now when `UserFactory` is begin resolved, `IHttpContextFactory` inside `UserFactory` will also be resolved.

Comment: How can I use `UserFactory`? Can you please provide a full solution?

Comment: Where do you use it now? For example: you can inject an instance in your controller using constructor injection.

Comment: I already have context in the controller. What about other places? Code man I need code please.

Comment: In what other places do you need it beside a controller? It's always the entry point for a request. Also, begging for code like this won't get you far.

Comment: I need it throughout the app to get the username/user id and with what you gave me I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I think you should read into [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET 5](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc6/) first.

Comment: that shows how to inject in the controller but anywhere else how can I get an instance of a `IHttpContextAccessor`? If I put in the constructor I still need to pass it an implementation when creating an instance of 'UserFactory'